# Vue Router: does this.$router.push navigate to a new URL?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, html5-history

I read the documentation of vue-router (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

> This is the method called internally when you click a ,
>   so clicking  is the equivalent of calling
>   router.push(...)

As far as I know clicking router-link element navigates to the URL placed in "to" attribute. However, according to History API 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Examples), history.pushState(...) only changes the history and does not navigate to a new URL.

So... how can we explain this contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to define exactly what you mean by "navigate to a new URL"; to me it can mean either reloading the page at a new URL, or simply changing the URL in the address bar without reloading the page.

`history.pushState()` does change the URL, but it doesn't cause the browser to perform a full page reload as is typical when you click a link. This is how "single page apps" work – they intercept `<a>` clicks and use `history.pushState()` to prevent the page from reloading.

> history.pushState(...) only changes the history and does not navigate to a new URL.

Here I think "and does not navigate to a new URL" is wrong – it does, except the page doesn't reload.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction here. There is no reason why the Vue Router could not do a change to the url with the history api and change the component as rendered in various router-view components.

When you include a `router-link` in your code, this is a component like any other. Vue will render [this component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/components/link.js). The interesting part is this:

```
const router = this.$router

// And later
const handler = e => {
  if (guardEvent(e)) {
    if (this.replace) {
      router.replace(location)
    } else {
      router.push(location)
    }
  }
}

const on = { click: guardEvent }
if (Array.isArray(this.event)) {
  this.event.forEach(e => { on[e] = handler })
} else {
  on[this.event] = handler
}
```

For the history api, you can see [in the source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/history/html5.js) that for a `this.$router.push(..)` we transition, and we push the state with [this pushState function](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/ea8cb474f869a5a12a095fcb5989c45c68971d14/src/util/push-state.js). The transition itself can be found in [history/base.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/history/base.js).